# How to fix " - " to be shown in a string in Java?

Tags: java

I have a problem where in my code below. I try to set my label to show " - " on particular string if the job_group has a " " then set the label with " - ". But, in this case the job_group does not show " - " inside the string? Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;


@ManagedBean(name = "jobSearchItemMapper")
@ApplicationScoped
public class JobSearchItemMapper implements RowMapper {
 @Override
    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
        JobSearchItem jobItem = new JobSearchItem();

    jobItem.setid(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD") + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + rs.getString("JOB_GROUP"));
    jobItem.setValue(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD") + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) +  rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") );

       if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").equals(" ")) {

          jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")   +  " - "   +   rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") + " (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD"))   + "-" + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")");

      } else {

        jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")    +     " - " +    rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") + " (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD")) + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")");

      }

       if (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE").equals("0")) {

       jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")  +   "  " +  rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") + " (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD")) + ")");

        } else {
            jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE") +   "  " +  rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") + " (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD")) + "-" + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")");
        }

        return jobItem;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  A log statement inside the if and else would be a good start.

Comment: Your question specified `if the job_group has a " "`, but your code checks for complete equality, meaning, if the job_group actually literally is a space.  It's not clear if that is intentional or perhaps that is the source of your bug.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").equals(" "))
```

to:

```
if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").trim().isEmpty())
```

to cover any case of `rs.getString("JOB_GROUP")` containing spaces.
Inside the if block remove `rs.getString("JOB_GROUP")` since it is empty:

```
jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")   +  " - (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD"))   + "-" + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")");
```

Comment: hey @forpas, thanks for your answer. But, `" " ` is not empty it does have a value thats comes from my database. I say that if job_group is equals to " ", set the label.

Comment: What value? Other than space (ascii 32)?

Comment: the values are stored in the database, where I try to match it with job_class with job_group being " "

Comment: @SwiftingAllTheWay if it is 1 or more spaces, then `trim()` will remove them and leave the string empty. This is why I used `trim()` and `isEmpty()`.

Comment: But, the values are not empty though. It just thats the way I insert job_group to be " " in the db

Comment: Then why do you compare to `" "`? You must debug and check what is this value that looks like a space but it's not and compare to  that value.

Comment: so, when I watch it for job_group it says ""

Comment: Just to make sure, check its length with `rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").length()` if it is `0`

Comment: its length is 1.

Comment: No, there is an unprintable char inside the string. Get its ascii value by int ascii = (int) rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").charAt(0);

Comment: ascii value is `32`

Comment: ascii value 32 is the space.

Comment: So use the code as it is in my answer and it must work.

Comment: so when I add `if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").equals("32"))` I dont see the " - " ?

Comment: No it's not the string "32" it's a space that has ascii code 32 like any char has an ascii code.

Comment: I tried `if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").trim().isEmpty()) {``  jobItem.setlabel(rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")   +  " - (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD"))   + "-" + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")");
        ` but is not working.

Comment: What is not working? Since `rs.getString("JOB_GROUP")` is not printed you should see a `'-'` instead of `rs.getString("JOB_GROUP")`. Isn't this so?

Comment: mhmm.. but, I need the `'-'` to be printed between the job group and job title ..

Comment: also `if (rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").trim().isEmpty())` is `null`

Comment: The  job group is **empty** what should it print? In your code you have `rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_TITLE")   +  " - "   +   rs.getString("JOB_GROUP") + " (" + (rs.getString("JOB_CLASS_CD"))   + "-" + (rs.getString("PAY_GRADE")) + ")")`. If you remove from it job group all the rest will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to compare against an empty string rather than " " so I would do

```
String jobGroup = rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").trim();

if (jobGroup == null || jobGroup.isEmpty()) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
String test="This is a test";  
String myString=test.replace(' ','-');//replaces all occurrences of ' ' with '-'  
System.out.println(myString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me either confusing " " and "". I suggest you not to test if the String you are looking for is empty the way you do it but use some helping class like the Apache StringUtils Class: 
    `StringUtils.isEmpty(string);` or rewrite your if statement like this to make sure you catch the right cases:

`rs.getString("JOB_GROUP").equals(String.EMPTY)`

Hope this helps debugging.